# Are there any significant omissions, deletions, or differences between the Reeve-era Superman movies and the novelizations?

Tags: dc, adaptation-comparison, superman-1978

Are these books strict novelizations?   Do they show any significant divergence from the final version of the films?   Were they written based on the theatrical releases?

Comment: @Valorum -- did you see this one too?

Comment: I saw it.......

Comment: @Valorum:  Are you psychologically capable of leaving this question unanswered?

Comment: I'm interested to see whether anyone puts together an answer. In the meantime I've got some feelers out to get hold of the books so I can cross-compare with the scripts that I've already got

Comment: @Valolum:   :-)   :-)

Comment: There is a novel Superman: Last Son of Krypton by Elliott S. Maggin, published in 1978 when the movie Superman (1978) came in.  it was promoted as a tie-in to the movie but has a totally different plot.  However, Today I learned it was based on an original movie script written years before the Supeman (1978) movie script and so isn't a novelization of Superman (1978) at all.  The differences don't matter because they are totally different stories.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman:_Last_Son_of_Krypton

Comment: There was a novelization of "Superman and the Mole-Men"? Ooooh The OP meant Christopher Reeve, not Steve Reeves. Never mind.