# Are there any significant omissions, deletions, or differences between Superman Returns and its novelization?

Tags: dc, superman, adaptation-comparison, superman-returns

Is this book a strict novelization? Do it show any significant divergence from the final version of the film? Was it written based on the theatrical releases or earlier scripts?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't know.

Comment: Tough question.

Comment: @NeoDarwin:   This question is playfully directed at Valorum who claimed to have pretty much all novelizations except two Superman ones.

Comment: @Valorum:  [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/203034/are-there-any-significant-omissions-deletions-or-differences-between-the-reeve)